# Anchor image and text height not correct

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to create a tab with the internal text and image as a link. The problem I am facing is the anchor dimensions and/or positioning seem to be different than the image. As you can see in the jsfiddle link, there is some spacing between the bottom of the image and the bottom of my div and I can't figure out why that is there.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/XLeGd/)

---

If you can't access that link, HTML code:

```
<div id="SapDataBtn">
    <a href="#">
        <img runat="server" src="http://i.cubeupload.com/Tm2tPF.png" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="SapBtnText">
        Data
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#SapDataBtn {
  background-color: #c7ddf2;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 90px;
}
#SapDataBtn a:link,
#SapDataBtn a:visited,
#SapDataBtn a:hover,
#SapDataBtn a:active {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #19456e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#SapDataBtn img {
  border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Did my solution worked for you? If so, please mark it as accepted for others to see.

Comment: @Big00d Woh there skippy. I can't accept an answer before the 10 minute mark.

Comment: No problem, just saying ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:bottom;` in your `#SapDataBtn img`, this should do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like below... it will help you...

```
#SapDataBtn img {
  border-style: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XLeGd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you looking for:

```
#SapBtnText {
    vertical-align: super;
}
```